# viewpager scrollview not working android

Tags: android

I'm integrating `ViewPager` and `ScrollView` on android but it doesn't seem to work. The `ViewPager` scroll works just fine but the `ScrollView` does not work at all on all the solutions I've tried. Below is my MainActivity class and xml layout.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    hostDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.host_description);
    hostDescription.setTypeface(quickSandRegular);
    hostDescription.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    View header=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // set navigation font
    Menu m = navigationView.getMenu();
    for (int i=0;i<m.size();i++) {
        MenuItem mi = m.getItem(i);

        // apply font to subment
        SubMenu subMenu = mi.getSubMenu();
        if (subMenu!=null && subMenu.size() >0 ) {
            for (int j=0; j <subMenu.size();j++) {
                MenuItem subMenuItem = subMenu.getItem(j);
                applyFontToMenuItem(subMenuItem);
            }
        }

        applyFontToMenuItem(mi);
    }

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

}
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- here insert your scrollview and all views you need for this page this is actually your page -->
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutMain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/welcome_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
                    android:background="@color/blue"
                    android:textSize="26dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/intro_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="Save on your next adventure."
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
                    android:background="@color/blue"
                    android:textSize="28dp"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dip"
                    android:background="#cccccc" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/host_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Become a Host"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="21dp"/>

            <!--<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/sv" />-->

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/host_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Earn money sharing your extra space"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="17dp"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:background="#cccccc" />
        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/host_telxt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Become a Host"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="21dp"/>

                <!--<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/sv" />-->



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/host_escription"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Earn money sharing your extra space"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="17dp"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dip"
                    android:background="#cccccc" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

**ImageAdapter**

```
class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return IMAGES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        imageView.setImageResource(IMAGES[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `android:scrollbars="vertical"` inside *Scroll View*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` and write your logic in `onPageScrollStateChanged`

```
@Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
         ScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(!(!lastPage && state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE));
}
```

You need to write logic to find if you are on last page or not which is simple.

Comment: what does the lastPage variable signify?

Comment: create a boolean variable to determine if you are on last page in viewPager or not

Comment: like private boolean lastPage = false;

Comment: yes, and in getItem(position) of your adapter set it if you are at last position

Comment: kindly share a sample Adapter with the discussed implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122886/discussion-between-joeabala-and-nayan-srivastava).

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by customizing layout_height of the ViewPager. Below is the code:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/view_pager2"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="300dp"
     android:paddingLeft="20dp"
     android:paddingRight="20dp"/>

ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
        viewPager.setPadding(70, 0, 70, 0);

class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return IMAGES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            imageView.setImageResource(IMAGES[position]);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            setPrimaryItem((View) container, position, object);
            //   lastPage = IMAGES[position]==object;
        }
    }
```